# Vue CSS переиспользуемые классы

Tags: css, vue.js, vue3

Как во Vue сделать переиспользуемый класс?
Например,я хочу чтобы класс .button был глобальным для всех компонентов, а .test-button только для этого компонента. Как это можно сделать?

```
<template>
  <button class="button test-button"></button>
</template>

<style scoped>
.button {color: red;}
.test-button {background: green;}
</style>
```

Comment: Когда у тега `<style>` есть атрибут `scoped`, то его CSS будет применяться только к элементам текущего компонента. (c) документация

Comment: @Jour а как правильно тогда делать? Создать два тега - со scoped и без него?

Comment: я бы создал отдельный файл css в котором прописал глобальные классы... отсутствие scoped врятле перенесет классы на все уровни) скорее всего они будут доступны в дочерних компонентах, не более